# Assessing linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I don't quite understand how my lecturer derives this. In linear regression we have:

$y = \hat{y} + \textrm{e}$

where the variables above are nx1 vectors. Then he writes:

$y^Ty = \hat{y}^T\hat{y} + \textrm{e}^T\textrm{e}$

Where if one expands $y^Ty$ one gets:

$y^Ty = \hat{y}^T\hat{y} + 2\hat{y}^T\textrm{e} + \textrm{e}^T\textrm{e}$

where $\hat{y}^T\textrm{e} = \textrm{e}^T\hat{y}$ because it's a scalar.

I don't understand where the $2\hat{y}\textrm{e}$ term goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $$\hat Y' e =(X\hat\beta)'(Y-X\hat\beta) = \hat \beta'X'Y - \hat \beta'X'X\hat\beta =\hat \beta'X'Y - \hat \beta'X'X(X'X)^{-1}X'Y= \hat \beta'X'Y -\hat \beta'X'Y =0$$